# URL: I can't pass "SELECT" statement to PHP connection string

Tags: php, database, select

I have hosting domain in Godaddy, when I pass a "SELECT" statement string to my PHP file it works fine, like "example.com/test.php?stm=select * from users" (by escaping spaces for sure), but if I add "WHERE" to the statement like "example.com/test.php?stm=select * from users where id = 1" I gut this message:
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

So, is this a problem in Godaddy hosting or I made any mistake?

Comment: Why would you even want to pass SQL through the querystring? I mean, you do realise this is a **huge** security risk right?

Comment: What if you escape “=” to “%3D”?

Comment: Godaddy probably have some sort of request "firewall" running there, that looks for common exploit patterns in the passed parameters, and then blocks such requests.

Comment: Hi Nayef, what if somebody else tries "example.com/test.php?stm=delete from users". Be careful it is risky.

Comment: I used this statement from inside my App, so nobody can see it!

Comment: Also I tried to make some coding like replace "SELECT" to SESESE then decode it from PHP, it works with small statement but fails in long one